# How to work around VBA OnTime character limitation?

Tags: excel, vba

I need to run a VBA subroutine 4 seconds later. The subroutine takes one string parameter. The problem I'm having is that the string I need to pass appears to be too long and it's erroring out. Try running this code:

```
Sub DoTest()
  Application.OnTime Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 4), "'PrintStr ""aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa""'"
End Sub

Sub PrintStr(str As String)
  Debug.Print str
End Sub
```

DoTest() runs without errors. Now add one more "a" to the string of a's and run DoTest() again. You will get a "This macro ... cannot be found" error.

How can I work around this, either using OnTime or another solution that would allow me to call a subroutine that accepts a parameter X number of seconds later? I'm using Excel 2003.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
Dim str As String

Sub DoTest()
    str = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 4), "PrintStr"
End Sub

Sub PrintStr()
  Debug.Print str
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick solution! Another DOH! moment ^^